# how to remove array String substring() Method using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to know how can I remove the First word in the string using JavaScript?

For example, the string is "mod1"

I want to remove `mod`..I need to display `1`

```
var $checked = $('.dd-list').find('.ModuleUserViews:checked');
                var modulesIDS = [];
                $checked.each(function (index) { modulesIDS.push($(this).attr("id")); })
```

[image: SEE]

Comment: what is the scenario of that string, say will it always ends with the number or you always want to remove the first three characters of the string, How?

Comment: i want to remove first three character @RajathMS

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method. The following will give the last character of the string.

```js
var id = "mod1"
var result = id.substring(id.length - 1, id.length);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: @IvinRaj, can't you use this in your array? What is the problem?

Comment: modulesIDS.push($(this).attr("id").substring(3, 4));

Comment: @IvinRaj, can I ask you to do some effort? You should put in some research yourself also. You should of course apply `substring` to the value, not to the array. But you do know what an array is and how to access its elements, since you already have code doing that... so what is the problem?

Comment: thank you `modulesIDS.push($(this).attr("id").substring(3, 4));` it's working

Comment: instead of specifying the end number '4' directly mension the string length. Otherwise it will return only the 4th character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var arr = ["mod1"];
var replaced= $.map( arr, function( a ) {
    return a.replace("mod", "");
});        
console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all letters and keep only the numbers in the string, you can use a regex match.

```js
var str = "mod125lol";
var nums = str.match(/\d/g).join('');
console.log(nums);
// "125"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to split the string (faster, less memory consumed), you can use indexOf() with substr():

```js
 var id = "mod1"
 var result = id.substr(id.indexOf(" ") -0);
 console.log(result)
```